# What happens when a file that is imported is importing a file that the file importing it is also importing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I have three files:
- main.js <- dependencies: module.js, helper.js
- module.js <- dependencies: helper.js
- helper.js <- no dependencies

Both main.js and module.js are importing from helper.js; and main.js is importing from module.js

The functions main.js is importing from module.js uses functions from helper.js

When I run main.js: will helper.js be imported twice, once by main.js and once by module.js, or will helper.js be imported only once by main.js?

main.js:

```
    import {someFunction} from "./helper.js";
    import {someOtherFunction} from "./module.js";
    someFunction();
    someOtherFunction();
```

module.js:

```
    import {someFunction} from "./helper.js";
    function someOtherFunction(){
        // do something using someFunction();
        someFunction();
    };
    export {someOtherFunction};
```

helper.js:

```
   function someFunction(){
       // do something
   }; 
   export {someFunction};
```

Comment: For future reference you could easily test this by adding a logging statement to the file you're importing — if it logs twice then the file is parsed twice. To answer your question though, the file will be loaded once and both main and module will share the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module will always be loaded once.

The ES 262 spec states on page 413:

> [Importing a module] must be idempotent if it completes normally. Each time it is called with a specific
>   referencingModule, specifier pair as arguments it must return the same Module Record instance.
>
> Multiple different referencingModule, specifier pairs may map to the same Module Record instance. The actual mapping
>   semantic is implementation-defined but typically a normalization process is applied to specifier as part of the mapping
>   process. A typical normalization process would include actions such as alphabetic case folding and expansion of
>   relative and abbreviated path specifiers.